# Difference between defining a constant and beginning with it in a structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, logic

For example, let's suppose that I have my structure $\langle\mathbb{R},+\rangle$ and that $\exists!x\forall a\in \mathbb{R}(a+x=x+a=a)$ as an axiom. In this case $0:=x$. But what if I consider the structure $\langle\mathbb{R},+,0\rangle$ and state that $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}(a+0=0+a=a)$ as an axiom. Does this mean the same thing? are they equivalent?

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind but for example a morphism from $(R,+)$ to $(S,+)$  does not need to preserves the "defined constants".

Comment: @azarel Good point! and the constant $0$ is preserved when there's a morphism between $\langle \mathbb{R},+,0\rangle$ and $\langle \mathbb{S},+,0\rangle$, right?

Comment: Let $T_1$ be say group theory over the language with just $+$, and the usual axioms, including your $\exists!x\dots$. Let $T_2$ be the theory over the language with $+$ and the constant symbol $0$, with the usual axioms, including the second one you mentioned. Then there is a simple mechanical way to transform a sentence $\phi$ of the second language into a sentence $\phi$ of the first language, so that $\phi$ is a theorem of $T_2$ iff $\phi'$ is a theorem of $T_1$.